# How to get the senders' position (coordinates) in Windows Form Application?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, sender

I just began learning *WinForms* and am currently baffled on how to get the *senders'* (mouses') position (coordinates). I tried searching but to no avail.

This is my, somewhat, of a try but, sadly, it ended up with an error:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_MouseHover(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(sender::Position.X - 5, sender::Position.Y - 5);
    MessageBox::Show("Foo", "Bar", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Stop);
}
```

So my question here is quite clear, I think: how can I get the *senders'* position (in this case, the mouses'). Explanations would also be of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find a valid answer I took the longer route.

Firstly, I declared a `boolean` in the `namespace` with the value of `false` (it will change to true when the mouse will touch the picture). Then I create two new methods: one to get the `X` and `Y` of the mouse and execute code if the mouse is touching the picture and the second one to determine whether the mouse is touching the picture or not.

```
private: System::Void picture_MouseMove(Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) {
    int VMouseX = e->X,
        VMouseY = e->Y;
    if (VMouseEntered) {
        VMouseEntered = false;
        this->picture->Location = System::Drawing::Point(VMouseX + 17, VMouseY + 17);
    }
}

private: System::Void picture_MouseEnter(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    VMouseEntered = true;
}
```

Then, I create two new `EventHandlers` for the picture. The first `EventHandler` is to listen for mouse movement, the second one is to check whether the mouse is touching the picture.

```
this->picture->MouseMove += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::picture_MouseMove); // Checks for mouse movement.
this->picture->MouseEnter += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::picture_MouseEnter); // Checks whether the mouse is touching the picture.
```

Done. I hope that this will help someone.